# Unexpected variable issue

Tags: php, mysql

Now all I am getting is the same value what ever I put in. So its just reading the first if statement and that is it and outputting the same price.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "insuredcars");
if ($_POST['formcar'] == '1' || $_POST['formage'] == '18' ||  $_POST['formNCD'] == '0' || $_POST['formPoints'] == '0' )
{
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM insurance WHERE insuranceid = '3'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> The price for insurance will be " . $row['insuranceprice'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";    
}
else if ($_POST['formcar'] == '6' || $_POST['formage'] == '18' ||  $_POST['formNCD'] ==      '0' || $_POST['formPoints'] == '0' )
{
$query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM insurance WHERE insuranceid = '2'");

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> The price for insurance will be " . $row['insuranceprice'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
}
  else if ($_POST['formcar'] == '1' || $_POST['formage'] == '19' ||  $_POST['formNCD'] ==     '0' || $_POST['formPoints'] == '0' )
{
  $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM insurance WHERE insuranceid = '5'");

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td> The price for insurance will be " . $row['insuranceprice'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: where is the error and what it is

Comment: added the brackets in but still get the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp\htdocs\search.php on line 16

Comment: Consider separating concerns - don't mix MySQL, PHP and HTML on the same script: you'll end up with unmaintainable and unreusable code.

Answer (score 2):

In PHP, conditions without braces `{` and `}` will only execute a **single** line after it. You need to add some braces.

```
<?php

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "insuredcars");
    if ($_POST['formcar'] == '1' || $_POST['formage'] == '18' ||  $_POST['formNCD'] == '0'   || $_POST['formPoints'] == '0' ) {
        $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM insurance WHERE insuranceid = '1'");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td> The price for insurance will be " . $row['insuranceprice'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
    } elseif ($_POST['formcar'] == '6' || $_POST['formage'] == '18' ||  $_POST['formNCD'] == '0' || $_POST['formPoints'] == '0' ) {
        $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM insurance WHERE insuranceid = '2'");
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> The price for insurance will be " . $row['insuranceprice'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";

?>
```

I'm not sure what was going on with the `<tr>` part, but yeah, this is a good start for you.

Answer (score 0):

You `if` statement doesn't have brackets ... try this :

```
if(cond1){

}else if(cond2){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Many `{` were missing or ill-placed. I tried to to guess their position. Try the corrected syntax below and see if it works as intended.

```
if ($_POST['formcar'] == '1' || $_POST['formage'] == '18' ||  $_POST['formNCD'] == '0' || $_POST['formPoints'] == '0' )
{
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM insurance WHERE insuranceid = '1'");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td> The price for insurance will be " . $row['insuranceprice'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";    
}
else if ($_POST['formcar'] == '6' || $_POST['formage'] == '18' ||  $_POST['formNCD'] == '0' || $_POST['formPoints'] == '0' )
{
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM insurance WHERE insuranceid = '2'");

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> The price for insurance will be " . $row['insuranceprice'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";
}
else if ($_POST['formcar'] == '1' || $_POST['formage'] == '19' ||  $_POST['formNCD'] ==     '0' || $_POST['formPoints'] == '0' )
{
    $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM insurance WHERE insuranceid = '5'");

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> The price for insurance will be " . $row['insuranceprice'] . "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

**Notes:**

Aside from the position of the brackets, there are some logic errors in your code. For instance:

- the first `if` block is should be executed `if ($_POST['formage'] ==
  '18')`… fine…
- …but so should your else statement… which doesn't make sense.

My guess is that you meant `&&` instead of `||`, but that's only a guess.

Comment: I have changed it to that which is great but for some reason I am getting the same value all the time. It's like it's just reading the first if statement and that is it.

Comment: Well, aside from the position of the brackets, there are some logic errors in your code. For instance, the first `if` block is should be executed `if ($_POST['formage'] == '18')`… fine, but so should your else statement… which doesn't make sense. My guess is that you meant `&&` instead of `||`, but that's only a guess. Maybe you should learn more about control structures in general and boolean operators before going on with your code.